p-torsion in the Tate-Shafarevich group of supersingular elliptic curves
Let $E$ be a supersingular elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$. Is something known on the $p$-torsion of the Tate–Shafarevich group in this case? In particular, I would like to know if (or if known under which additional assumption) it vanishes.
